# How to iterate through eloquent object which has multiple records?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

**I am using following code to fetch records from table:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use App\Http\Requests;
//use App\tempLogin;

class loginController extends Controller
{
    public function checkCredentials(Request $request){

        $mobile = $request->mobile;

        $users = App\tempLogin::where('mobile','=',$mobile)->get();


        return $user->name;

    }
```

But this is the eloquent object so it throwing me a error. what will be the else way to do it?

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: I simply return Var_dump($users) so i got output like object.

Comment: you say "it throwing me a error"?

Comment: `$user` is not defined, but `$users` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo

```
$users = \App\tempLogin::where('mobile','=',$mobile)->get();//you are getting $users
```

& returning

```
return $user->name;
```

So change it to

```
return $users->name;
```

But I still have a doubt it will solve your problem as you are using **`get`** & get returns a **`collection`** unless you have a relation in **`tempLogin`** model.

> So I assume you have a record in DB which has **`mobile`** equal to
>   something & you want to return the name of that if this is the case
>   then you can use this solution

```
$users = \App\tempLogin::where('mobile','=',$mobile)->firstOrFail();//source https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L299-L306
```

then return

```
return $users->name;
```

> If you have multiple records in DB & you want to do a **`get`** then
>   you can do it like this way

```
$users = \App\tempLogin::select(['name'])->where('mobile','=',$mobile)->get();
```

This will only select **`name`** from table

Now you can return

```
return $users;
```

Which will be a collection of **`tempLogin`** Model & if you use it in view as api it will be automatically be JSON encoded using laravel request like this

```
[{"name":'YOUR_NAME_OF_THE_RECORD'},{"name":'YOUR_NAME_OF_THE_RECORD'}]
```

Or if you want to return the record as an array you can use like this

```
$users = \App\tempLogin::select(['name'])->where('mobile','=',$mobile)->pluck('name')->all();
return $users;
```

This will return an array like this

```
[
 "YOUR_NAME_OF_THE_RECORD",
 "YOUR_NAME_OF_THE_RECORD",
]You have a typo

$users = \App\tempLogin::where('mobile','=',$mobile)->get();//you are getting $users
```

& returning

```
return $user->name;
```

So change it to

```
return $users->name;
```

But I still have a doubt it will solve your problem as you are using **`get`** & get returns a **`collection`** unless you have a relation in **`tempLogin`** model.

> So I assume you have a record in DB which has **`mobile`** equal to
>   something & you want to return the name of that if this is the case
>   then you can use this solution

```
$users = \App\tempLogin::where('mobile','=',$mobile)->firstOrFail();//source https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L299-L306
```

then return

```
return $users->name;
```

> If you have multiple records in DB & you want to do a **`get`** then
>   you can do it like this way

```
$users = \App\tempLogin::select(['name'])->where('mobile','=',$mobile)->get();
```

This will only select **`name`** from table

Now you can return

```
return $users;
```

Which will be a collection of **`tempLogin`** Model & if you use it in view as api it will be automatically be JSON encoded using laravel request like this

```
[{"name":'YOUR_NAME_OF_THE_RECORD'},{"name":'YOUR_NAME_OF_THE_RECORD'}]
```

Or if you want to return the record as an array you can use like this

```
$users = \App\tempLogin::select(['name'])->where('mobile','=',$mobile)->pluck('name')->all();
return $users;
```

This will return an array like this

```
[
 "YOUR_NAME_OF_THE_RECORD",
 "YOUR_NAME_OF_THE_RECORD",
]
```

Comment: but i have duplicate mobile no. in db so it will fetch multiple records and thats why i want to loop through $users.

Comment: this won't work because ->get() will return a collection. not a model. you need to iterate or use indexed access to get a model property.

Comment: But in documentation there is given that we can loop through collection.

Comment: @ARIF...I changed something like this :                                                                $users = tempLogin::where('mobile','=',$mobile)->get();                                 Can i access names now??

Comment: No you can't because it's a **`collection`** & you want to access the property of the model which is inside of the collection you can access name only if it's a model instance

Comment: But when i use $users = App\tempLogin::where('mobile','=',$mobile)->get();  it throw an error "FatalThrowableError in loginController.php line 17:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\tempLogin' not found"

Comment: And tempLogin model is already there. But why it is asking for tempLogin controller i don't know.

Comment: use like this **`\App\tempLogin`** instead of this **`App\tempLogin`** when you use it appends the namespace from current namespace so to call **`tempLogin`** you have to call from root by adding a slash in front of it. But for use statement you can ignore the beginning slash e.g `use App\tempLogin;` & then you can use like this  `tempLogin::where('mobile','=',$mobile)->get();`

Comment: But i want to loop on $users. Still it is giving me error.

Comment: Thanks @ARIF you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `$user` variable which is undefined. You should iterate over collection to get single user:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you loop the collection items like this:

```
$users = App\tempLogin::where('mobile','=',$mobile)->get();

if($users->count() > 0)
{
   forach($users as $user)
   {
      // do something with the App\User model
      $name = $user->name;
   }
}
```

but if you want to access the users collection as array, change the query like this:

```
$users = App\tempLogin::where('mobile','=',$mobile)->toArray();
```

then you can access it like this:

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
    // now the $user contains an array containing each row data.
    $name = $user["name"];
}
```

if you want to access single user:

```
$user = App\tempLogin::where('mobile','=',$mobile)->first();
$name = $user->name;
```

this will fetch the first (offset 0, limit 1) row to you. You need to specify the order to get the desired first row.

Comment: I changed it to like:                                                                         $mobile = $request->mobile;
$users = tempLogin::where('mobile','=',$mobile)->toArray();
     return $users;